# Can a class own a content manager in python?

Tags: python-3.x, contextmanager

I have a class that manages some shared resources and currently provides a get_X() and put_X() method to access the resources. A better interface for this would be to use a context manager for each resource as in

```
with ResourceManager.X() as x:
   # do stuff
```

But my use is a QT5 Widget class that grabs the resource then it gets configured and has to release the resource when the widget is destroyed:

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.Widgets.QTableWidget):
    def conf(self):
        self.x = ResourceManager.get_x()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        ResourceManager.put_x()
        super().closeEvent()
```

So is there a more pythonic way analog to the context manager "with" construct to keep a resource allocated for the livetime of a class?

Note: Qt5 doesn't allow multiple inheritance

Update:

The Qt5 UI file loader doesn't allow passing arguments to `__init__` so I have added the `conf()` method to configure custom widgets after the UI files are loaded. That's why the `ResourceManager.get_x()` isn't in `__init__`.

What I would like to do is to get rid of the `put_x()` call. I want the resource to be automatically freed by python when the class is deleted. There are many widgets and resources and it's easy to forget a `put_x()` somewhere so I don't want to balance get/put calls manually.

Another concern is exceptions when multiple resources are used. If the exception happens after say the 3rd resource then only those 3 should be released. Another thing I don't want to track manually.

Answer (score 0):

Never used QT before, but the first thing that comes to my mind are the `__init__` and `__del__` methods, called respectively when a class instance is created and destroyed.

You could try the following:

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.Widgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = ResourceManager.get_x()

    def __del__(self):
        ResourceManager.put_x()
        super().__del__()
```

My unique concern is that QT actually deletes the class if it's not used anymore.
Try it and let me know

```
    super().closeEvent()
```

Comment: That's basically what I use already. I want to get rid of the `put_x()` call and have the python GC call that when the class is actually deleted.